# Magento API list only one column for example SKU from Products

Tags: php, api, magento

How to use Magento API function (catalog_product.list) to get list of product but I don't want to get ALL data of product from magento (i want to get in response from Magento API only ONE column - attribute - list of product IDs only or better attribute). Is it possible to filter response? I need this to decrease connection transfer usage.. if its impossible how can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Theres nothing to show just simple call to product list. I don't see anythink in API docs to restric list fields or add custom attribute to list API mathod. I will write custom API(its not that much to do but i hope Magento API has it...) but if anybody have better idea thx for info